# mutation of input in formik through custom function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have n input field which as for initials

The system must change the populated initials once the cursor leaves the field into capital letters and each letter must followed by one dot.

For example:
abcdefghij   -> convert into A.B.C.D.E.F.G.H.I.J.
Th.B.             -> convert into T.H.B.
Abcdefghijk -> cannot convert, invalid (more than 10 characters populated, show error 101041)

these are the conditions that need to be fulfilled

right now i am have tried a mutation function

```
  alphadotter: (value: string): string => {
    return value
      .toString()
      .replace(/[^a-z\u00DF-\u00F6\u00F8-\u00FF\.]+?/gi, '.')
      .replace(/\.+/gi, '.')
  },
```

but its not working I am sure there is something with the regex, the value is the value coming from the input field